# Run one value through multiple functions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, palindrome

I want to create a function "palindromes()" which checks whether a value is a palindrome (spelled the same forwards and backwards). 
In order to do that, I have created 4 functions, which:

1. Makes all letters small
2. Removes all non-letter characters
3. Reverses the ensuing array, and finally...
4. Checks whether that array is a palindrome.

See functions bellow:

```
  function makeSmall(input) {
    lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
    return lowerCase;
  }

  function keepOnlyLetters(input) {
    var patt1 = /[a-z]/g;
    var onlyLetters = input.match(patt1);
    return onlyLetters;
  }

  function reverseArray(array) {
    var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
    return reversedArray;
  }

  function checkPalindromes(array) {
    var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] != reversedArray[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

How do I make sure that the function "palindromes()" takes one value and runs it through all these functions to finally give me an answer (true or false) of whether that value is a palindrome or not?

Best regards,
Beni

Comment: You need to store the return value of each function and pass **that** value to the next one.

Comment: `reverseArray` looks quite useless when it isn't used in `checkPalindromes` for reversing the array.

Comment: so you want `keepOnlyLetters(makeSmall(str))` then you'll need to change the string to an array ... so, you could `reverseArray(keepOnlyLetters(makeSmall(str)).split('')).join('')`

Comment: if there isn't much need of these 4 functions you can combine them all in a single and execute it.

Comment: PS: I suggest you find a good javascript tutorial. This question is quite well posed and formatted, so it would feel wrong to downvote it, but usually i do for any question which should be covered by a decent tutorial. [In future versions of JS](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/wiki) you can potentially write something like `str |> makeSmall |> keepOnlyLetters |> checkPalindromes`. But it will still take time and the syntax may still change.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I hate that syntax... Like where does it end if you don't put a semi? What if the nextline is a template literal? UNSAFE NEWLINES! NO!

Comment: @RobertMennell Operator precedence always applies. ASI is a pain and anyone who omits semicolons is asking for it. It's not an issue of said syntax.

Comment: @ASDFGerte true enough

Answer (score 5):

There's a point of diminishing returns with functions. When calling the function is just as short as using the body of the function inline, you've probably hit that point. For example, `makeSmall(input)` is really no improvement to just using `input.toLowerCase()` inline and will be slower and harder to understand. `input.toLowerCase()` is already a function; it's just wasted work to wrap it in another function.

Having said that, to answer your question, since all your functions return the value that's input to the next, you can put you functions in an array and call `reduce()`:

```
function palindromes(input) {
    return [makeSmall, keepOnlyLetters, reverseArray, checkPalindromes].reduce((a, c) => c(a), input)
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `diminishing returns with functions` and the interesting use of `reduce` although I'm not sure that it's better in terms of readability as opposed to just composing them.

Comment: You should mention the pipe function https://30secondsofcode.org/adapter#pipefunctions `const pipeFunctions = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)));`

Answer (score 2):

So first before trying to do composition at first it sometimes works best to do it sequentially to make sure you understand the problem. As you get better at composition eventually you'll know what tools to use.

```
function checkPalindrome(string){
 return string
  .toLowerCase()
  .match(/[a-z]/g)
  .reverse()
  .reduce(function ( acc, letter, index ) {
    return acc && string[index] == letter
  })
}

checkPalindrome('test') // false
checkPalindrome('tet') // true
```

Okay good we understand it procedurally and know that there are four steps. We could split those four steps out, however since two steps require previous knowledge of the array state and we don't want to introduce `converge` or `lift` just yet we should instead just use a [`pipe function`](https://30secondsofcode.org/adapter#pipefunctions) and combine the steps that require a previous state. The reason for that is eventually functions just lose how much smaller you can make them, and attempting to split those steps up not only hurts readability but maintainability. Those are not good returns on the effort invested to make two functions for that part!

```
function pipe (...fns){
  return fns.reduce( function (f, g){
    return function (...args){
      return g(
        f(...args)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

All this function does it it pre-loads(composes) a bunch of functions together to make it so that the output of one function applies to the input of the next function in a `left to right` order(also known as array order).

Now we just need out three functions to pipe:

```
function bringDown(string){ return string.toLowerCase() } // ussually called toLower, see note

function onlyLetters(string){ return string.match(/[a-z]/g) }

function flipItAndReverseItCompare(arrayLike){  // I like missy elliot... ok?
  let original = Array.from(arrayLike)
  return original
    .slice()
    .reverse()
    .reduce(function (acc, val, ind){
      return acc && val == original[ind]
    })
}
```

Now we can just pipe them

```
let palindrome = pipe(
  bringDown,
  onlyLetters,
  flipItAndReverseItCompare
)

!palindrome('Missy Elliot') // true... and I never will be
palindrome('Te t') // true
```

Now you're well on your way to learning about function composition!

Comment: Error in `flipItAndReverseItCompare` should be: `return original.slice().reverse()` because [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) mutates original and will cause all strings passed to it to return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can just string the function calls together like this...

```
var input = 'Racecar';

if (checkPalindromes(reverseArray(keepOnlyLetters(makeSmall(input))))) {
   alert("It's a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: That's horrible to read. You should explain composition and some design patterns to make it easier to read

Comment: That's true. I wouldn't do it this way in a real project. I was just showing the simplest way of passing a single value through a series of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call them in a nested fashion and return the final result in your palindrome function.

Sample Code: (with changes indicated in the comments)

```
function makeSmall(input) {
    // Added var to prevent it from being a global
    var lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
    return lowerCase;
}

function keepOnlyLetters(input) {
    var patt1 = /[a-z]/g;
    var onlyLetters = input.match(patt1);
    return onlyLetters;
}

// This function is not really needed and is unused
/*function reverseArray(array) {
    var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
    return reversedArray;
}*/

function checkPalindromes(array) {
    var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != reversedArray[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// New Palindromes function
function palindromes(input){
    return checkPalindromes(keepOnlyLetters(makeSmall(input)));
}
```

Note:

You don't really need so many functions to do this. I'm putting this here as a strict answer to your exact question. Other answers here show how you can solve this in shorter (and better?) ways

Answer (score -1):

try the following snippet.

```js
    function makeSmall(input) {
        lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
        return lowerCase;
    }

    function keepOnlyLetters(input) {
        var patt1 = /[a-z]/g;
        var onlyLetters = input.match(patt1);
        return onlyLetters;
    }

    function reverseArray(array) {
        var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
        return reversedArray;
    }

    function checkPalindromes(array) {
        var reversedArray = array.slice().reverse();
        for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
          if (array[i] != reversedArray[i]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    var result = checkPalindromes(reverseArray(keepOnlyLetters(makeSmall("Eva, Can I Stab Bats In A Cave"))));
    
    console.log(result);
```

Notice how functions are called one after the other in one line.